# VBA formatting Cells

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet that I want to conditionally format. I want to format each cell in a certain column based off 2 other cells in the same row. Each row has a different number and some rows don't have numbers at all.

Example: I want G16>D16+E16+H16 and G16

Here is my Code:

```
'Format measured dimensions
Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("G16").End(xlDown)


    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , 
"=AND($G16>$D16+$E16,$E16<>"""",$F16<>"""")")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , 
"=AND($G16<$D16-$E16,$E16<>"""",$F16<>"""")")

    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
       End With

         With cond2
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
```

Comment: `Set rg = Range("G16").End(xlDown)` - this ends up with only *one* cell, not the range from `G16` to the end. To verify, `Debug.Print rg.Address` and check the Immediate Window.

Comment: It set the same formatting for each cell and in the immediate window it says `$G$1443`

Comment: That is only *one* cell: `Set rg = Range("G16", Range("G16").End(xlDown))` would be the entire range.

Comment: Now it is showing the range but it is applying the format for Row 16 to all cells. is there a better way to do this? Maybe all new code?

Comment: Get the conditional formatting to work *manually* first maybe. I don't get what you mean by applying the format for Row 16 to all cells.

Comment: All cells read `=AND($G16>$D16+$E16,$E16<>`, `=AND($G16<$D16-$E16,$E16<> `when i look at manage rules window.

Comment: Right. That's the way it should be. But when the conditional formatting is executed for row 17, for example, since the `16` in the formula is relative, Excel "updates" the 16 to 17. You're just looking at the "original" formula in the rules window.

Comment: Perhaps an [overview](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) of conditional formatting would be helpful, as it seems like it's not so much the code that is the question.